# Java Google Analytics

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, google-analytics, desktop-application

I am trying to incorperate Google Analytics into a java project. The documentation is not very clear on teh desktop side (but extremely clear for mobile development) of implementaion. I have included the necessary JAR files, however, am not sure how to send a sample pageview to my analytics dashboard. Are there any tips/tutorials that would help a first-timer to desktop java analytics?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.